# String data, right truncation while using fast executemany with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am struggling with

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 636 buffer 510', 'HY000')

while using `executeMany()` with `__crsr.fast_executemany = True`. When I remove this line everything works fine.

I am using `pyodbc` (`4.0.30`) and `MSSQL` with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`.

My database table looks like 4 columns and each of them is `varchar(255)`.

I already to add this line: `crsr.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, 50, 0)])` and add `UseFMTOnly=yes` to connection string but it didn't work.

Could you guys help me, please? I am already tired of that.

Comment: Welcome! Please see "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)," include relevant code and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Could you point me what I did wrong, please? It seems to me that I told everything what I could. My database structur, version of pyodbc, pointed a database server and used driver. I told when and which exception occurs. Is there anything I could do else? :(

Comment: "length 636" indicates that you are trying to insert a string of 318 characters (636/2) into a column whose maximum width is 255 characters.

Comment: If you're still having related issues: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/380

Answer (score 0):

Check the ODBC Driver you are using in your pyodbc connection string, if it is an old version, errors could be misleading, use for example:
driver="{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"

instead of:
driver="{SQL Server}"